# How to properly define timezone on date value from database

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, timezone, php-carbon

I'm making a to-do application which needs someway of checking if a task has passed the end_date.

**Problem:** I have the end_date stored in my database but whenever I retrieve this date as a Carbon object, The timezone is defined as `'UTC'`. I want to manipulate this timezone to be `timezone('Europe/Brussels')`. If I adjust the timezone there will be 2 hours added on the end_date because the Brussels timezone is `UTC+2`. I don't want any hours added to the current stored time

**Question:** What is the best way of adding a timezone to the date without changing the date itself? I want this because the user enters the date in the Europe/Brussels timezone instead of UTC.

**Code:**

**My input fields:**

```
{{Form::date('end_date', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Brussels'),['class' => 'form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0'])}}
{{Form::time('time', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->timezone('Europe/Brussels')->format('H:i'),['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

**Adding the date to the db:**

```
$requestData = $request->all(); 
$task = new Task($requestData);
$task['end_date'] = $requestData['end_date'].= ' ' . $requestData['time'] .= ':00';
$task['user_id'] = auth()->id();
$task->save();
```

**Fetching the date:**

```
$task = Task::find(35);
dd($task->end_date);

// Result

Carbon @1534560960 {#550 ▼
       date: 2018-08-18 02:56:00.0 UTC(+00:00)
       }

$task = Task::find(35);
dd($task->end_date->timezone('Europe/Brussels'));

// Result

Carbon @1534560960 {#550 ▼
       date: 2018-08-18 04:56:00.0 Europe/Brussels (+02:00)
       }
```

2 hours being added, any tips on how to deal with this?

Comment: You are not setting the timezone to brussels when you create the datestamp to store in the db.  However, once you do that, there will be a 2-hr discrepancy between “old” dates stored previously and newer ones.  The alternative is to pretend that the utc date you get back from the database is already in “brussels” time.  This falls apart quickly if you have to do stuff with other timezones.

Comment: How do I store it in the Brussels timezone on the db? If I know the dates will be stored in UTC isn't there a way of subtracting the date that the user has given? So when I fetch the date and add the timezone it actually matches the user's date

Answer (score 2):

If you use MySQL, it doesn't store timezone data in datetime field. So it is better to store all datetime values in UTC and transform it to required timezone when showing to the user.

If the user enters date and time in Europe/Brussels timezone, you should convert it to UTC before storing in MySQL and convert back to Europe/Brussels when showing to the user.

In the place where you're saving data to DB, you can use this code:

```php
$inputDateAndTime = $requestData['end_date'].' '.$requestData['time'].':00';
$task['end_date'] = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $inputDateAndTime, 'Europe/Brussels')->timezone('UTC');
```

Initially you create datetime object in user input timezone Europe/Brussels and immediately convert it to UTC.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET time_zone = "+00:00";//Adjust your Time Zone
```

You can manipulate view while adjusting date with the above query.